# Android: which operator for modulo (% doesn't work with negative numbers)

Tags: java, android, modulo

If I try

```
int a=(-2)%6
```

I get -2 instead of [4](http://www.google.si/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=-2+%25+6).

Why does it behave this way with negative numbers?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`%` does a remainder operation in Java.

To get a proper modulus, you can use the remainder in a function:

It's shortest using ternary operator to do the sign fixup:

```
private int mod(int x, int y)
{
    int result = x % y;
    return result < 0? result + y : result;
}
```

For those who don't like the ternary operator, this is equivalent:

```
private int mod(int x, int y)
{
    int result = x % y;
    if (result < 0)
        result += y;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @don roby: what this operator means: return result < 0? result + y : result; thanks

Comment: @Kenji - see [wikipedia on ternary operator ?:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 12):

Because if you divides -2 by 6, you will get -2 as remainder. % operator will give the remainder just like below;

```
int remainder = 7 % 3;  // will give 1
int remainder2 = 6 % 2; // will give 0
```

To get the modulo:

```
    // gives m ( mod n )
public int modulo( int m, int n ){
    int mod =  m % n ;
    return ( mod < 0 ) ? mod + n : mod;
}
```

Comment: OK, but then how do I get mod in Android?